# Place Bullet at the start of axis (Amcharts 4)

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I have a horizontal bar chart and I need to place bullets at the start of an axis like on the screenshot.
[image]

So far I've managed to place bullets like that.
[image]

I tried to use `x` and `dx` but from my understanding they work only with absolute values and that's not my case.

I see from the markup that bullet has a `transform` attribute on its element. I noticed that a value for X axis does the job for me, but how can I set it from code?
I know that I can set a custom class for bullets and set `transform: translate` in css, but I would like to place bullets the other way if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `locationX` property in `bulletsConfig` solved the problem.

```
bulletsConfig: [
      {
        type: 'LabelBullet',
        locationX: 1,
        label: {
          text: '{categoryY}',
          fontSize: 12,
          horizontalCenter: 'right',
          dy: -15,
        },
      },
    ],
```

[image: Final result]